# Power BI Report Builder - SharePoint as data source

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, sharepoint-online, powerbi-datasource

Is it possible to use [Power BI Report Builder](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58158) to connect to a SharePoint list?

It seems that it was possible to do that with the old SSRS Report Builder - [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200803021054/http://www.technicaloverload.com/use-sharepoint-list-data-source-ssrs-report/).

I would like to Build a SSRS-like report with Power BI using different SharePoint lists as Data Sources. I tried to use the Power BI Desktop app to build a report but I couldn't matrix/tables/sections repetitions.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the latest update([July 2019](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-support-for-non-premium-power-bi-datasets-in-power-bi-paginated-report-builder/)) of Power BI Report Builder, **you can use NON-PREMIUM datasets from Power BI Service as a data-source for Report Builder**.

So you can simply create a Dashboard in Power BI desktop **[from any SharePoint list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-sharepoint-online-list)** and publish it in your work-space. To create a dataset from a SharePoint list, go to `Get Data > Online Services > SharePoint online list` and add fill in the details. Then Publish your dashboard in your workspace.

Once that is done, you can use that dataset in your report builder.

**Check the image below:**

[image: Report Builder - Power BI Dataset]

Note: You can also Schedule a Refresh on your dataset so that your data is up-to-date.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked about a *SharePoint* list.

Answer (score -2):

Get data->More, you could find SharePoint Online List option.

[image]

Comment: That one I know, the one I need if the for the Power BI Report Builder - https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-paginated-report-builder-now-available/

_"To kick off our series of posts this month we’re calling “New Feature Friday”, we’re pleased to announce the initial release of Power BI Report Builder, the latest companion application for Power BI that lets you author Paginated Reports. It is a free, standalone Windows Desktop application that can be downloaded from the Power BI site."_

Comment: Same as SSRS create new dataset (Query in Power BI using Get Data), Point to different Table/Matrix and that will populate data as coming from the independent sharepoint lists.