# Power BI Report Builder is importing fields with the wrong data type

Tags: powerbi, sharepoint-online, reportbuilder

First off, I apologize if this is the wrong place to post this.

I want to create paginated reports off of a SharePoint list. To do this I created a dashboard in Power BI Desktop and Published it to a workspace, like mentioned in this question ([Power BI Report Builder - SharePoint as data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55911800/power-bi-report-builder-sharepoint-as-data-source)). I am then using that data source in Power BI Report Builder. All seems to be good, except that it is importing all fields as text. I have verified that the fields in question are listed as number fields in SharePoint and in the query in Power BI Desktop. Everything that I can tell has been published properly. I've tried everything that I can think of so any ideas would be appreciated.